# phonegap and playbook - upload file

Tags: cordova

I'm using the following code to upload an image. It works fine for android and iphone but not for playbook. I'm using phonegap 1.4.1 - It always calls the fail function below and the alerts show always 'undefined'. 
config.xml is according to blackberry sample. The application works except the upload function.

Thanks in advance.

...

```
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();

        options.fileKey="file";

        options.fileName=pictureFlag.substr(pictureFlag.lastIndexOf('/')+1).split('.')[0];

        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var param = new Object();

        param.fromEmail = $('#recipeDetailsFromEmailId').val();

        param.to = $('#recipeDetailsToEmailId').val();

        param.emailType = $('#recipeDetailsSendEmailId').attr('checked');

        param.sendMeCopy = $('#recipeSendEmailCopyId').attr('checked');

        param.message = $('#recipeDetailsMessageId').val();

        param.imageType = imageTypeFlag;

        param.language = localStorage.language;

        param.recipeName = nameFlag;

        param.prepTime = prepTimeFlag;

        param.serves = servesFlag;

        param.picture = pictureFlag.split('.')[0] + '.' + pictureFlag.split('.')[1];

        param.ingredients = ingredientsFlag;

        param.preparation = prepDescriptionFlag;

        param.deviceId = devicePlatform.toLowerCase();

        param.category = $("#selectCategoryId option[value='" + categoryFlag + "']").text();

        options.params = param;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();

        ft.upload(pictureFlag, url, win, fail, options);
```

...

function fail(message) {

```
//alert(message)

//alert("evt.target.error.code: " + message.target.error.code);

alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + message.code);

alert("upload error source " + message.source);

alert("upload error target " + message.target);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a `true` option at the end of the `upload` function like so :

```
ft.upload(pictureFlag, url, win, fail, options, true);
```